# Download and parse HTML without displaying it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, webkit

I have just read different stuff about `NSXMLParser`, `NSURLConnection`, `WebKit` and more, but I don't know how to do this: I have a URL to a website and I would like to get the source of this website to read and later store relevant information.

Some guidance to the right direction would be appreciated, Fabian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your HTML, all you have to do is use a NSURLRequest to make a request to your website, then use the NSURLConnection to issue the request, this will return with some data that is the html source, from there you can do what you wish. I am going to post an example of how to make a request synchronously, just be aware that you probably want to do this async...Also here is a ref to [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSURL *yourURL = [NSURL URLWithString: urlstring ];
NSURLRequest  *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:yourUrl];
NSData* data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
//now you can use the data and the websites encoding to get a string
```

Comment: Since the original poster seems a bit (understandably) confused by the many nested NS* classes, you might want to explicitly add a

Comment: Since the original poster seems a bit (understandably) confused by the many nested NS* classes, you might want to explicitly add a: NSURL *yourURL = [NSURL URLWithString: urlstring ]; to the front of that example. I think what's confusing to newbies is this regression of NS* classes : you need to create a NSURLRequest before you can make the NSURLConnection, and you need a NSURL to make the NSURLRequest.